# Extend WiFi range with a wired AP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, ssid

My brother has a router with wireless connections in his cellar/ground floor. His range is bad on the top floor.

He already has physical CAT cables running through his house so he could easily connect a new AP on his top floor. Could the wired AP provide the same SSID and thus the same network essentially. Is this a specific feature or should this be available on all modern wireless access points?

Comment: It would work, but personally I'd use different SSIDs & set the remote AP to not use DHCP. You can then choose the 'best' AP manually rather than hope they fight it out cleanly, & only the main router is controlling DHCP/DNS etc

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't believe those specific WAP things you can buy come with routing capabilities so no DHCP and such.

Comment: depends. Some do, some don't

Answer (score 1):

> Could the wired AP provide the same SSID and thus the same network
>   essentially. Is this a specific feature or should this be available on
>   all modern wireless access points?

Almost all APs, even the cheapest ones will let you set whatever SSID you want.
But as @Tetsujin mentioned, you don't want to just pray your devices connect to the right AP at the right time.

What you want is "Roaming" ability, so that the devices automatically get handed over to the nearest AP. Look into the Ubiquiti Unifi range. They are relatively affordable and my experience with their gears have been quite good. Pretty much set and forget. I have a set of 3 in my house, spread out over 3 floors.